# Add version to vs get_instance in SoftLayer API

Tags: ibm-cloud-infrastructure

Can the OS version be added to the vsManager get_instance output same as it is for the hardwareManager get_hardware output please.

Alternatively: How do I lookup the OS version from the "softwareDescriptionId" for a VS Instance?

```
# DEBUG
hardwareManager.get_hardware(hardware_id)
...
"operatingSystem": {
  "softwareLicense": {
    "id": 1064,
    "softwareDescription": {
      "manufacturer": "CentOS",
      "name": "CentOS",
      "referenceCode": "CENTOS_5_64",
      "version": "5.8-64"
    },
    "softwareDescriptionId": 992
  }
},
...


vsManager.get_instance(instance_id)
...
"operatingSystem": {
  "softwareLicense": {
    "id": 902,
    "softwareDescription": {
      "name": "CentOS"
    },
  "softwareDescriptionId": 887
  }
},
...
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the default mask from [VSManager](https://github.com/softlayer/softlayer-python/blob/master/SoftLayer/managers/vs.py) doesn't show the version, however, it can be solved adding an object mask, make the following change in your code please:

```
vsManager.get_instance(instance_id, mask="mask[operatingSystem[softwareLicense[softwareDescription]]]")
```